# How do i write responsive emailer

Tags: html, css

I am facing problem to make image responsive in Newsletetter means HTML Email.

I can make that image responsive in Browser but failed to do when I send that HTML as emailer into outlook version. That emailer needs to be responsive in mobile and tablet as well.

Comment: Some code you've written so far please.

Answer (score 2):

Though your question is really broad, I will try to give you information to get started.

Email templates is HTML from back in the 90s. That means, you create code, meant to work on prehistoric browsers (You can test your templates in IE6, or Microsoft Word for example. If it works in there, you've made a pretty good template).

Above information straight away proves to be the problem with what you are asking. How are you going to make something responsive, from the time that responsive wasn't in any way connected to the web?

Though responsive didn't exist back then, max-/min-width did exist back then, which will probably be the way to go.

For some examples you might want to check out [this link (Zurb Responsive Email Templates)](http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-email-templates) or [this link (HTML Email Boilerplate)](http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/#f2).

Apart from that, we aren't really able to help you, given that you haven't shown us the work you have done so far.

Edit: And tagging it CSS3 is also not very handy, since I don't think ANY email client supports it.